# How do I add a screenshot to an Allure report?

Tags: junit5, allure, selenide

I have a Selenide+Java project which uses allure reporting. I am using the TestExecutionListener to handle browser setup, but I am having some extreme difficulty figuring out how to add screenshots to the report on a test failure.

I'm using

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And in my Listener code:

```
public class BrowserListener implements TestExecutionListener {

    Browser browser;

    @Override
    public void executionStarted(TestIdentifier testIdentifier) {
        if(testIdentifier.isTest()) {
            browser = new Browser();
            browser.openBrowser();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void executionFinished(TestIdentifier testIdentifier, TestExecutionResult testExecutionResult) {
            //code here to log failed execution - ideally would like to put screenshot on failure
            browser.close();
    }
}
```

How do I add a screenshot to an Allure report using Selenide/Junit 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get this working by adding the following:

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.Configuration;
import com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide;
import com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.platform.engine.TestExecutionResult;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.TestIdentifier;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner.getSelenideDriver;
import static io.qameta.allure.Allure.addAttachment;


@Override
public void executionFinished(TestIdentifier testIdentifier, TestExecutionResult testExecutionResult) {
if (testExecutionResult.getStatus().equals(TestExecutionResult.Status.FAILED)) {
        try {
            File screenshotAs = ((TakesScreenshot) getSelenideDriver().getWebDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            addAttachment("Screenshot", FileUtils.openInputStream(screenshotAs));
        } catch (IOException | NoSuchSessionException e) {
            // NO OP
        } finally {
            WebDriverRunner.getSelenideDriver().getWebDriver().quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: works great! It should be marked as a final solution :)